# I'm stuck on how to "match" 2 columns of date and time in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

first timer here.

I've been stuck on creating a formula to calculate how many "leads" were created and modified on the same day with the "B2C Lead Name" being a name. I've redacted some numbers and names for obvious reason.

As you can see, row 8 and 9 for both column B and D fall on the same date. And B2C Lead Name is "Boom." On the top right corner, I've tried multiple ways I could think of to count the instances where the lead was created on Aug 30 and was also modified on Aug 30 while the Lead Name is Boom, but I haven't managed to have it work when at least my formula should've shown 3.

For context, I'm creating a report for my sales team and I've been stuck on this thing for 3 weeks, so any help on this would be extremely appreciated. And if it's not too much to ask, please also school me on why using DATEVALUE and trying to "match" those time and date columns as a criterion doesn't work?

Please let me know if you need any more details on this. Thank you!

Here's what I've been staring at for the past 3 weeks, among countless others: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTUNIQUEIFS(NMZHImport!$A:$A,NMZHImport!$G:$G,"*"&U30&"*",DATEVALUE(NMZHImport!$B:$B),"="&DATEVALUE(NMZHImport!$D:$D),NMZHImport!$N:$N,"<>Appointment Confirmation"))`

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymruu.png)

Comment: An image is not helpful as far as testing and writing formulas. Please provide a link to an actual spreadsheet with the data shown in the image. Otherwise, you are expecting that the volunteer contributors here should start their own spreadsheet and spend the time to manually enter your data before they could even begin to think about your problem. And that will be a deterrent to many.

Comment: Hi Erik, 

Sorry for the hassle. It's just a bunch of real customer details, but i've gotten rid of them. Thank you for your help. I'll try your formula tomorrow. Have a great day!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lk4OLpiNMyPjAaZN5TWqH76XWKkEsgDYkl-5PmXzmu8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula I provided works. I just tested it against your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment to your original post.

That said, given the data as I see it, try this untested formula:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A8:A, INT(B8:B)=DATEVALUE("8/30/2022"), INT(B8:B)=INT(D8:D), E8:E="Boom")))`

`FILTER` will form a virtual array of only those entries in A8:A where the day-only date (obtained by `INT`) in B8:B is equal to your target date, where that date is also equal to the value in D8:D, and where the value in E8:E is "Boom".

`IFERROR( )` will return null if there are no matches (which would otherwise be an error).

`COUNTA` will count the filtered list (if any).

If this does not work as expected, follow my suggestion in the comment I left to your original post and share a link to your sample data in a spreadsheet.